# ActiveMessaging without Rails -- JMS Property Name Issues

Tags: ruby, jms, message-queue, stomp, activemessaging

I've been trying to figure out how to send JMS messages from Ruby. I've setup StompConnect to interface between JMS and Ruby, using Stomp on the Ruby side.

I can talk to my queues using telnet, but was having trouble getting Ruby to speak to StompConnect properly.

Now I'm attempting to use ActiveMessaging to do the communication piece, and I have written my own poller script. The following error message is thrown after the queue is created and the message is sent:

> => Subscribing to /queue/HelloWorld (processed by ApplicationProcessor)
>   No-one responded to "[C4043]: Illegal character used in property name - -"}' body='javax.jms.JMSException: [C4043]: Illegal character used in property name - -
>   at top level in at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.MessageImpl.checkValidPropertyName(MessageImpl.java at line 757
>   at top level in at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.MessageImpl.checkAndSetProperty(MessageImpl.java at line 821
>   at top level in at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.MessageImpl.setObjectProperty(MessageImpl.java at line 2054
>   at top level in at org.codehaus.stomp.jms.StompSession.copyStandardHeadersFromFrameToMessage(StompSession.java at line 234
>   at top level in at org.codehaus.stomp.jms.StompSession.convertFrame(StompSession.java at line 257
>   at top level in at org.codehaus.stomp.jms.StompSession.sendToJms(StompSession.java at line 69
>   at top level in at org.codehaus.stomp.jms.ProtocolConverter.onStompSend(ProtocolConverter.java at line 260
>   at top level in at org.codehaus.stomp.jms.ProtocolConverter.onStompFrame(ProtocolConverter.java at line 132
>   at top level in at org.codehaus.stomp.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java at line 131
>   at top level in at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java at line 680
>   ' >

Now, there isn't a '-' in any property that I'm setting. Is this maybe an issue with the Stomp library itself? This is more or less the same problem I was running into trying to talk to StompConnect from Ruby in the first place.

How are others managing to get around this, communicating with JMS from Ruby? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah seems like your server does not allow '-' in the property name.  You might want to try out the [apache apollo stomp server](http://apollo.apache.org) .  It does not have that restriction.

Comment: I think I'll be looking into ActiveMQ first as it seems to support JMS out-of-the-box -- thanks for pointing me to this!